# Using DTS to transfer database schema where tables have multiple owners

Tags: sql-server, dts

I have a database schema in SQL 2005 that I want to copy to a SQL 2000 server. It contains tables that have multiple owners. When I try to create a DTS package to transfer the schema I get conflicts because some of the tables have the same name (but different owners). It looks like it is trying to make all the tables to be owned by dbo.

Is there a way to preserve the ownership on the destination server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is no way to do this via DTS so I ended up scripting the database and recreating it from that script.